# How to stop the table from being built again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I've got a lovely table function from josh.trow @ [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626155/how-should-i-build-a-simple-4x4-table-with-fill-able-blocks) that builds a 4x4 table which can be filled with color. The only problem is is that it rebuilds itself every time I call the function (hence the first time I call the file I see a 4x4 table, the second time I see a 8x4 table, and so on.) It doesn't multiply the rows because they are already limited to 4.

I can't see what check I need to put in that limits the table's columns to only being built once. (4)

Here's the JS code:

```
function repeatedFunction(L, G, P, D) {
jQuery.fn.reverse = [].reverse;

var completeData = [L, G, P, D];
var max = 4;
$.each(completeData, function(intIndex, objValue) {
    if (objValue > max) max = objValue;
});
for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) 
{
    $('#statSheetTable').append('<tr id="resultRow' + i + '"></tr>');
    $.each(completeData, function(intIndex, objValue) {

    $('#resultRow' + i).append('<td name="column' + intIndex + '" ></td>');
    });
}

$.each(completeData, function(intIndex, objValue) {
    $('td[name=column' + intIndex + ']').reverse().each(function(idx, val) {
        if (idx < objValue) $(this).addClass('complete' + intIndex);
    });
});
}
```

---

I tried using a global variable, which stopped the table from being duplicated, but then my color filling code was not functioning (as it can't be refreshed with the new instructions to fill with color).

Essentially what I added to the above function was:

```
var firstTime = true;
.....
function repeatedFunction(L, G, P, D, 4) {
if(firstTime == true)
{
    .....
    // code from above block
    .....
    firstTime = false;
}
```

---

Do your experienced JS eyes see where I can limit the table from building more columns?

Comment: @Briz: That jQuery.fn.reverse shouldn't be inside the function - you can see where I use it it is only called once - appropriate since it modifies the global jQuery object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go chief, updated as you asked.

EDIT: Whoops, now it works :)

http://jsfiddle.net/X83ya/2/

Comment: Again, you've made me very happy. Thanks for sharing your table-building wisdom with me! And this time, you got the answer :D

Comment: @Briz: don't forget my comment - the jQuery.fn.reverse definition should NOT be in the function.

Answer (score 0):

First, always use identical comparison operators when comparing boolean values:

```
if(firstTime === true)
```

That being said, you don't need it if you just want to rebuild your table. `$('#statSheetTable').append(...` will just "add to" whatever was in there. Make sure you clear it out in the beginning like such:

```
...
var max = 0;
$('#statSheetTable').html('');
...
```

Comment: Either == or === doesn't change the outcome, which is that the columns are not being rebuilt, BUT it also damages the color-filling functionality of my method. I need both the columns to not be rebuilt and the rest of the function to work properly